# Efeito css/js de card Flip não funciona no safari

Tags: javascript, css, safari

Tenho um código simples que desenvolvi, de um efeito card flip, exemplo abaixo.

Funciona no google tranquilo, porem me deparei que no safari tem um bug quando o card se vira, pesquisei sobre, encontrei alguns prefixos para safari mas não consigo encontrar uma solução, falta algum prefixo de suporte para o safari?

O bug no safari é que quando o card vira com o click, não aparece o fundo, apenas a frente.

```js
let card  = document.getElementById("card")

let frente = true

card.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (frente == true) {
    card.style.transform = "rotateY(180deg)"
    frente = false
  }
  else {
    card.style.transform = "rotateY(0deg)"
    frente = true
  }
  event.stopPropagation()
})
```

```css
body, .content, html {height: 100%}
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; font-family: sans-serif;}

.content {
  align-items: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #dfe9f3 0%, white 100%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  perspective: 600;
}

.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px #444;
  height: 480px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 320px;
}

.card .side {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card .back {
  background-color: #fff;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 102;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div id="card" class="card">
    <div class="side">
      side
    </div> <!-- .side -->
    <div class="back">
      back
    </div> <!-- .back -->
  </div> <!-- .card -->
</div>
```

obs: o erro acontece somente no safari.

obs: tenho este código no codepen caso ajude https://codepen.io/lennon/pen/qMPqGX

Comment: Qual versão do safari?

Comment: @MáttheusSpoo 11.2

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_transform.asp  `.style.transform` não é suportado pelo navegador safari.

Comment: Porque vc não cria uma classe tipo .ativa, e nela coloca as propriedades CSS que quer. e depois com JS vc apenas faz o toggle de classe tirando e colocando o CSS no click, tipo um toggleClass do jQuery

Comment: @MáttheusSpoo que mancada minha, mas não entendi como resolveria com JS?

Comment: @hugocsl boa ideia, vou testar.

Comment: Tente acrescentando outra linha com o prefixo no JS: `card.style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(180deg)"` e `card.style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(0deg)"`